# VBA: How to Change a Certain Value in duplicate Rows?

Tags: vba

I've got a tricky problem and couldn't find a way to solve it. Appreciated if anyone could give a helping hand.

For example, I get the data from system and want to get the result in Column [Target AHT]. If a case number appear for the 2nd times or above and the week number is the same as the first one, the target AHT column should be 0. Is there any formula or VBA code can solve this problem? I tried to figure it out but failed. Kindly please help. Thank you very much in advance!

---

```
Case Number  Week Number    Number of Activity  Sources     AHT     Target AHT
0001             1                 20             In         12         12
0002             2                 30             Out        15         15
0003             3                 22             In         17         17
0004             4                 35             In         18         18
0005             5                 23             Out        20         20
0001             6                 31             In         19         19
0003             7                 25             Out        16         16
0003             7                 25             In         16          0 
0003             7                 25             In         16          0
```

Kind Regards,
Aileen

Comment: Is you data always ordered by week number as shown? e.g. `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7 etc...`

Comment: Is the Table sorted by a surtain column? or is the order completely random?

Comment: Hi Alex and Winner, the data are not sorted by any column, just random, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done on Excel Formula using IF function if it is sorted by week / Case number.

Change the value for Target AHT to this formula for row F2 and copy the formula for the other rows.

```
=IF(B1=B2, IF(A1=A2,0,E2),E2)
```

Where I assume

Case Number - Row A
Week Number - Row B
Number of Activity - Row C
Sources - Row D
AHT - Row E
Target AHT - Row F

Comment: Thanks Sky for your answer. The data are randomly arranged, so your formula will only work if the same case in the same week stay next to each other and no more than 2 records.

Answer (score 0):

this is a little tricky.. I tested on my local host and it does what you want.. let me know if you have any questions.

UPDATE temp t1, 
(
    SELECT 
        id as unique_id, 
        new_name 
    FROM(
        SELECT
          id,
          IF(@ROW = Name, @COUNT, @COUNT := 1),
          CONCAT(Name, ' - ', @COUNT) AS new_name,
          @ROW := Name,
          @COUNT := @COUNT + 1
        FROM temp
        JOIN (SELECT @COUNT := 0, @ROW := "") AS t
        WHERE Name IN(SELECT Name FROM temp
        GROUP BY Name
        HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1)
    ) AS temp_test
) as testing
SET t1.Name = testing.new_name where t1.id = testing.unique_id
Final output looks like this: PICTURE

EDIT: This may work better for performance sake

1. FIRST RUN THIS QUERY

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;  -- longer if needed
SET @query1 := (
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT unique_name) 
FROM temp
JOIN(
    select Name as unique_name
    FROM temp
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1
) as t
);
2. THEN RUN THIS UPDATE

UPDATE temp t1, 
(
    SELECT 
        id as unique_id, 
        new_name 
    FROM(
        SELECT
          id,
          IF(@ROW = Name, @COUNT, @COUNT := 1),
          CONCAT(Name, ' - ', @COUNT) AS new_name,
          @ROW := Name,
          @COUNT := @COUNT + 1
        FROM temp
        JOIN (SELECT @COUNT := 0, @ROW := "") AS t
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET (`name`, @query1)
    ) AS temp_test
) as testing
SET t1.Name = testing.new_name where t1.id = testing.unique_id
I tested this on my local and it works so you should be able to get this to run :)

Comment: Hi Ennaciri, thanks for your prompt reply. I am working on excel and seems your solution doesn't work for this application.